# Video background creates horizontal scroll

Tags: css, video, background, scroll, html5-video

I'm working on a site where there is a video set as background in the top section. Currently, the video is scaling down as the viewport reduces, leaving whitespace at top and bottom. Following [this](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) tutorial, I found that a `min-height: 100%;` CSS property fixes the problem.
But this creates a horizontal scroll, since the video width is now wider than the viewport.

This is my markup:

```
<div id="cover">
   <video id="bgvid">
     <source src"..">
   </video>
</div>
```

And this is my SASS

```
#cover 
    position: relative
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
    height: auto
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
    box-sizing: border-box
    overflow: hidden

    video#bgvid
        overflow: hidden
        min-width: 100%
        min-height: 100%
        width: auto
        height: auto
        z-index: -1
```

I realize that the tutorial is using `position: fixed` on `#bgvid`, which removes the horizontal scroll but makes my video a fixed background on the rest of the page. Playing with the `width`  property also didn't help.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to your css.

That would remove the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does solve the horizontal scroll, but the rest of the page still aligns to the wider video. So the contents are actually center aligned to the width of the video, and not of the viewport. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't think of anything. You would think the `overflow: hidden` on the `#cover` would work. Could you add your code to a jsFiddle?

Comment: It wasn't possible to solve with pure HTML and CSS. After looking into it more my teammate solved it using [this](http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/) tutorial.